# is it possible to specify external channel in PrimeFaces push

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, atmosphere

My application is at http://example1.com and my push server is at http://example2.com.
Is it possible to specify the channel on example2.com in the push socket component in the channel attribute.
Something like `<p:socket onMessage="pushOnMessage" channel="http://example2.com/service/push" />`

Comment: is it just a different url to the same webapp? Then look [here](https://speakerdeck.com/player/827b32202f6f01321c076e02156363ec?slide=543#) otherwise I doubt it is possible

Comment: If we specify an external url in the web.xml as specifed in the userguide you provided the socket component listens to external primeface push server. But the problem is that when we push a message using eventbus in server side it considers the same application not to the url specified in the web.xml